# Running SQL script from Jenkins

Tags: sql, postgresql, jenkins, ssh

I have a Jenkins job that does the following -

1) SSH into a server 
2) Run a psql script

The script runs for 4 hours when I run it manually, but every time I run it from Jenkins it stops at 1 hr and 1 minute. I am not sure if this is happening because of a setting on Jenkins, Postgres or SSH. I basically need the script to run for the full 4 hours and not get killed at an hour and 1 minute.

**UPDATE**

This is how I run the code from Jenkins -

```
ssh server_ip sh -s << 'EOF'

sudo su

psql -U postgres -d db -f ~/runprocess.sql &> runprocess.log
```

Comment: Can you provide any code? How do you execute the script?

Comment: @mkemmerz I have updated the question with the code.